# How can I make a gradual slope with Unity Terrain tool?

Tags: unity, terrain

As the question title states, I am trying to make a gradual slope in Unity Terrain. I want it to be many 100's metres long for a golf course and it will slope in a few directions hopefully in places.

How could this be done with Unity Terrain?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? What's not working the way you want so far?

Comment: I've been trying but it makes the edges all be kind of circular and the slopes I can't control effectively where they should be . (I posted a picture above ...sorry delayed response, I crashed out after writing this lol!)  ... if I wanted to make the fairway slop upwards and left for example how can it be done? thanks

Comment: I think you don't need to make tool because there are ready tools to making what you want like `World Machine` or `Houdini (Procedural Modeling)`.can you paint sample from what you want In your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried smoothing your relief out?

You can also set the hardness of your terrain sculpting bush to have a smoother looking, more gradual slope instead of a harsh bump on your terrain.
Try also playing with the opacity of it so you can gradually build up the terrain.

Comment: hi a_rrat. thanks for the answer but sadly I have already explored all these options. I've decided to go much further back to basics to learn about terrains from scratch and how it will be best to affix textures to the terrain via coding. thanks for your help tho

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a few years old. But for anyone new looking for the solution.

The unity registry has Terrain Tools which lets you installed additional brushes and tools to the existing Unity Terrain.

[image]

Here's a link to the documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.terrain-tools@2.0/manual/effects-slope-flatten.html